# typeorm is not being installed, and keeps making npm error

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs, typeorm

I am working with a teammate whose environment is OSX while mine is Windows.
and we all have same version of node, npm, nestJS:

- node version: 18.5.0
- npm version: 8.12.1
- nestjs version: 9.1.8.

and when I try to install the dependency it keeps getting an error.
and the message is like this:

```js
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE<br>
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree<br>
npm ERR!<br>
npm ERR! While resolving: projectname<br>

npm ERR! Found: typeorm@0.2.45<br>
npm ERR! node_modules/typeorm<br>
npm ERR!   typeorm@"^0.2.45" from the root project<br>
npm ERR!<br>
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:<br>
npm ERR! peer typeorm@"^0.3.0" from @nestjs/typeorm@9.0.1<br>
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm<br>
npm ERR!   @nestjs/typeorm@"^9.0.1" from the root project<br>
npm ERR!<br>
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry<br>
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps<br>
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.<be>
```

when I tried to install `typeorm 0.3.0` it also made another error:

```js
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE<br>
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree<br>
npm ERR!<br>
npm ERR! While resolving: projectname<br>
npm ERR! Found: @nestjs/common@9.2.1<br>
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs/common<br>
npm ERR!   @nestjs/common@"^9.2.1" from the root project<br>
npm ERR!<br>
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:<br>
<br>
npm ERR! peer @nestjs/common@"^8.0.0" from @nestjs/testing@8.4.7<br>
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs/testing<br>
npm ERR!   dev @nestjs/testing@"^8.0.0" from the root project<br>
npm ERR!<br>
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry<br>
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps<br>
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.<be>
```

and when I tried to install with npm install `--legacy-peer-deps` I got a proxy error and I never use proxy. I don't know what is wrong.

and the dependencies I have:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^1.2.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^2.1.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^6.1.4",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
    "@pinata/sdk": "^1.1.26",
    "@types/cron": "^2.0.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1167.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "decimal.js": "^10.4.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "get-audio-duration": "^3.1.0",
    "ipfs-http-client": "^56.0.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "speakeasy": "^2.0.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.4.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "27.5.0",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "28.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
```

Comment: Could you please share the `devDependencies`?

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei sorry for inactivity, I added devDependencies

Answer (score 0):

You have typeorm 0.2.45 installed when `@nestjs/typeorm` requires that you use typeorm 0.3.0 or greater. Install the newer version of TypeORM and [migrate as necessary](https://typeorm.io/changelog#030httpsgithubcomtypeormtypeormpull8616-2022-03-17) as there are breaking changes

Comment: I should try this, thanks! some features I had only worked properly with v0.2.45 that was why I kept the version that way

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working in `dev` environment, *devDependencies* is also installed and makes the conflicts.

To fix this, you need to update `@nestjs/cli`, `@nestjs/schematics` and `@nestjs/testing` to **9.x.x**.